# Rbx.Lua - Why can't I store a .txt file as a table?

Tags: variables, lua, lua-table, httpservice, roblox

I have a python-based web server running on my raspberry pi that web scrapes trade currency rates on Roblox. If you don't know what I just said, all you need to know is that I am gathering numbers that change on a certain webpage. I want to import this collected information into my Roblox game so I can graph it (I already have the grapher made).

Here is what I did to import it:

```
bux = game.HttpService:GetAsync("http://tcserver.raspctl.com:5000/AvailableRobux.txt")
bux = {bux}
tix = game.HttpService:GetAsync("http://tcserver.raspctl.com:5000/AvailableTickets.txt")
tix = {tix}
```

This gives me a 404 response. If I access the web server from my computer (On the same network), it also gives me a 404 response. I know I am port-forwarding correctly because the following line of lua DOES work.

```
print(game.HttpService:GetAsync("http://tcserver.raspctl.com:5000/AvailableRobux.txt"))
```

I need the robux and ticket rates to be stored in a table. Go to one of the URLs with the rate data and you will see that it is already formatted for a Rbx.Lua table, it just needs the curly braces. How can I turn my data into a table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just convert a string to a table like that, you need to split the components into a table by splitting it along the delimiters (the commas). [See this page about splitting strings in Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin). I would suggest taking out the spaces and only having commas between the data entries.

Here's an example of what you'll need. The explode function is from the link I posted. I have not tested it.

```
function explode(d,p)
  local t, ll
  t={}
  ll=0
  if(#p == 1) then return {p} end
    while true do
      l=string.find(p,d,ll,true) -- find the next d in the string
      if l~=nil then -- if "not not" found then..
        table.insert(t, string.sub(p,ll,l-1)) -- Save it in our array.
        ll=l+1 -- save just after where we found it for searching next time.
      else
        table.insert(t, string.sub(p,ll)) -- Save what's left in our array.
        break -- Break at end, as it should be, according to the lua manual.
      end
    end
  return t
end

bux = game.HttpService:GetAsync("http://tcserver.raspctl.com:5000/AvailableRobux.txt")
bux = explode(",",bux)
tix = game.HttpService:GetAsync("http://tcserver.raspctl.com:5000/AvailableTickets.txt")
tix = explode(",",tix)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The provided script worked and the splitting strings page helped. I didn't need to remove the spaces though.